# zend framework 2 trigger event on a single module upon request (not on dispatch)

Tags: php, zend-framework

My app has multiple modules, among these are 2 CMS modules and a front module. I want to trigger the identity validation method only on the CMS modules on all actions. I want to do this in something like a front controller plugin (ZF1 refference) and the way I see it it should be in Module.php of the module in cause, but everything in here gets triggered across the entire app on dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Although your event handler will affect all modules, you can filter your CMS modules by their namespace. For example, if all controllers in your CMS module are named like 'CMSModule\Controller\IndexController', you can test if the namespace is CMSModule and do the identity validation, like in example below:

```
class Module {

 public function onBootstrap(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e){
   // ...
   $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
   $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
 }

 public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e){
   $match = $e->getRouteMatch();
   $controller = $match->getParam('controller');
   $segments = explode('\\', $controller);   
   $namespace = array_shift($segments);
   if(!$namespace=='CMSModule1' && !$namespace=='CMSModule2' && ...) 
      return;
   // Check the identity here
 }
}
```